# Angular google maps + PlacesService + unable to get latitude and longitude information in the results

Tags: angular8

I am using angular google maps and its PlaceService. I want to put markers on the map based on the location details that I am gonna get from the nearBySearch method. When fire a request I get all the information except 'latitude' and 'longitude'. Is there any solution for this?

[image]

My code is below:

```js
  searchNearby(lat: any, lng: any) {
    const locationOf = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    const requestObj = {
      location: locationOf,
      name: 'Tesco',
      radius: 10000,
      type: 'store',
    };
    // const map = document.getElementsBy('sebm-google-map-container')[0] as HTMLDivElement;
    const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.getElementById('output') as HTMLDivElement);
    service.nearbySearch(requestObj, (results, status) => {
        console.log('Retrieved data:');
        console.log(results);
    });
  }
```

```html
 <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<API_key>&libraries=places">
    </script>
```

The map has been added to index.html